# Probability reaching recurrent states Markov chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

For a Markov chain with states $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and transition probabilities matrix $$P=\begin{pmatrix} 1/2 & 1/4 & 1/4 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 0 & 1/3 & 0 & 0 & 2/3 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1/3 & 2/3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/3 & 2/3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2/3 & 1/3 \end{pmatrix}$$
 I want to find $\lim_{n \to \infty} p_{ij}^{(n)},i,j\in S$.

The classes $\{1\},\{2\}$ are transient and $\{3,4\},\{5,6\}$ are recurrent. For the recurrent states I have found stationary probabilities $(2/5,3/5)$ and $(1/2,1/2)$.

I am stuck with how to compute the probability of reaching the recurrent states $\{3,4\}$ and $\{5,6\}$. I know a theorem for reaching a set before another set using the total probability rule so I tried something similar. Let $$T=\min\{n\geq 0:X_n \in \{3,4\}\}$$ and $$h_i=P(T<\infty|X_0=i).$$ I want to find $P(T<\infty)$. I tried to use total probability: $h_3=1,h_4=1,h_1=p_{11}h_1+p_{12}h_2+1/4$ which gives me $1$ which I don't think is correct...

Comment: How the last relation give $1$? $h_1=\frac12 h_1+ \frac14 h_2 + \frac14$, $h_2=0$, then $\frac12 h_1=\frac14$ and $h_1=\frac12$, isn't it?

Comment: Please see update to my answer below, it is now complete...

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Why not just solve $x = xP$?

If you insist on doing this from first principles, note that you can absorb $\{3,4\}$ into one state, and $\{2,5,6\}$ into another -- now you have a 3-state chain with the first state transitive and the problem becomes much easier...

**UPDATE**

Following the suggestion of `NCh`, here is an elaboration. When you collapse the states as I mentioned, you get 3 states $A=\{1\}, B = \{2,5,6\}$ and $C = \{3,4\}$ with transition matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1/2 & 1/4 & 1/4\\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so to solve $x = xP$ we can solve $x(P-I)=0$ which implies $x_A=0$ and has $x_B$ and $x_C$ unconstrained.

Since from the statement of the problem, the states $B$ and $C$ are interchangeable, we have $x_B = x_C$ by symmetry, hence $x_B=x_C = 1/2$.

Now similarly you can solve the subsystem implied by $B$ and $C$ to get $x_2=0$ and $x_3=2/5, x_4=3/5, x_5=x_6=1/2$. Now when you recombine them with the conditional probability of ending up in $B$ and $C$ respectively you get
$$
x_1=x_2=0 \quad \text{and} \quad x_3=2/10, x_4=3/10, x_5=x_6=1/4.
$$

Comment: $x=xP$ leads to $\frac52 x_3+2 x_5=1$, $x_5=x_6$, $x_4=\frac32 x_3$, $x_1=x_2=0$. How can this help?

Comment: @NCh you also impose $\sum_i x_i = 1$ to get the unique solution

Comment: Isn’t 2 transient?

Comment: @user30523 yes, it is, but since you can only transition from $2$ to $5,6$, it helps to group it together since you want a minimal number of states in the chain...

Comment: @gt6989b This is also the result of equation $\sum_i x_i=1$. Try to realise your advice by yourself, please.

Comment: @NCh thanks for your advice, please see the update

Comment: @gt6989b $x=(0,0,1/4,1/4,1/4,1/4)$ does not saticfy equation $x=xP$.

Comment: @NCh sorry made an arithmetic error in reducing the matrix... updated with correct values

Comment: @NCh I think what you were getting wrong is that when you absorb the states, you end up with 2 constraints of the form $\sum x_i=1$...

Comment: @gt6989b I did not try to get anything, but only tried to understand your answer. Now the resulting probabilities are correct. This is the same answer that was already obtained by OP: the probability of transition to each absorbing class is $h_1=1/2$. And therefore the limiting probabilities are $$0,\ 0,\ \frac12\cdot\frac25,\ \frac12\cdot\frac35,\ \frac12\cdot\frac12,\ \frac12\cdot\frac12.$$ Here $\frac25$, $\frac35$ are the stationary probabiilties for first class of recurrent states, $\frac12$, $\frac12$ - for the second class.